# Know the port number to connect through putty as the machine is KVM accessible

Tags: putty, kvm-switch

I can access a remote ubuntu machine through Raritan KVM application. But I want to know the port number to which the machine is connected so that I can access through putty.

Is there any way to find that?

Comment: What KVM switch model is it? How are you accessing the machine through it currently? (Are you perhaps mixing up KVM switch ports and TCP ports?)

Comment: I connected the machine through Raritan KVM Application. No, I don't want the KVM switch ports. I need the port which we give in putty along with IP address of the remote machine.

Comment: well, if you are connecting via putty, what network protocol are you wanting to use (Telnet, RLogin, SSH)?

Comment: I want to use ssh connection to transfer a file to that remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

SSH access is normally on port 22.

However, if you're accessing the machine currently via a KVM, you either need to assertain from the KVM software if it offers port forwarding itself, or you'll need to find out the public IP of the server so you can connect directly to it (on port 22, unless the port has been changed.)

---

As [telcoM](https://superuser.com/users/784449/telcom) pointed out in the comments, if the only accessible IP of the server is in the private IP ranges (10.*.*.*, 172.[16..31].*.*, 192.168.*.*) then they might not be directly publicly accessible. If this is the case you'd need to talk to the provider about how you get access.

Comment: Also, if the IP address of the target machine is in one of the private address ranges (10.*.*.*, 172.[16..31].*.*, 192.168.*.*), then there is no guarantee that the target machine's IP address is reachable from where you are: there might be a firewall or a NAT box between your local system and the target machine, which might block the connection or change the IP addresses and/or port numbers.

Comment: Thanks @telcoM I thought that was obvious at first, but your comment made enough sense that I've included it in my answer.